# Is it possible to set a cooldown for one option in `discord.ui.Select`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have a problem with discord.py

I have `discord.ui.Select` and I want to put a cooldown for a single option. Is it possible?
Method for cooldown:

```
@commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
```

My select menu:

```
class Balselect(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, roles):
        super().__init__()
        self.roles = roles

    @discord.ui.select(
        placeholder="Выберите действие",
        min_values=1,
        max_values=1,
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Собрать Коллект",
                description="Получить доход вашего гос-ва"
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Экономика",
                description="Меняйте уровень экономики страны"
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Уровень жизни",
                description = "Развивайте вашу страну"
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Магазин",
                description="Покупайте военное оборудование"
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Управление страной",
                description="Распоряжайтесь вашим гос-вом"
            ),
            discord.SelectOption(
                label="Инвентарь",
                description="Просмотрите ваш инвентарь"
            )
        ]
    )
    @commands.cooldown(1, 3600, commands.BucketType.user)
    async def balselect(self, interaction, select):
        global inf, inf1, inf2, med, med1, med2, ind, ind1, ind2, res, res1, res2, tech, tech1, tech2, bruh, bruuh, cost, bemz, beemz, infrole1, medrole1, indrole1, resrole1, techrole1, infrole2, medrole2, indrole2, resrole2, techrole2
        if select.values[0] == "Собрать Коллект":
```

i have no idea how to do it

Comment: To my knowledge, there isn't a specific function to do so with discord.py. You could try using a your own external timer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a built-in function for this in `discord.py`. In this example, I used an external counter using [tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop).

```
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def balselect_cooldown():
  balselect_cooldowns_dict['universal counter'] += 1

balselect_cooldowns_dict = {'universal counter': 0}
```

Select view:

```
class Balselect(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @discord.ui.select(
        options=[
            discord.SelectOption(label='option 1'),
            discord.SelectOption(label='option 2')
        ]
    )
    async def selecting(self, interaction, select):
      current_count = balselect_cooldowns_dict['universal counter']
      userid = interaction.user.id
      # balselect_cooldowns_dict would look something like this
      # {'universal counter': 7, 987654321987654321: [{'option 1': [10, 6]}]}

      if userid in balselect_cooldowns_dict and \ # Below is to check if the selected option is in a dict
      any(select.values[0] in d for d in balselect_cooldowns_dict[userid]):
        # Getting the actual dict for select.values[0]
        cooldown_list = next(d[select.values[0]] for d in balselect_cooldowns_dict[userid] if select.values[0] in d)
        
        if current_count - cooldown_list[1] < cooldown_list[0]:
            await interaction.response.send_message(content="You're on cooldown!", ephemeral=True); return
        
        else:
          # Removing the cooldown from dict
          balselect_cooldowns_dict[userid] = [d for d in balselect_cooldowns_dict[userid] if select.values[0] not in d] 
          if balselect_cooldowns_dict[userid] == []: # Remove if not in use
            del balselect_cooldowns_dict[interaction.user.id]
          
      if userid not in balselect_cooldowns_dict:
        balselect_cooldowns_dict[interaction.user.id] = []

      cooldown = 10
      balselect_cooldowns_dict[interaction.user.id].append(
        {select.values[0]: [cooldown, current_count]}
      )

      await interaction.response.send_message(content=f'You selected {select.values[0]}', ephemeral=True)
```

This may not be the best way of doing it especially because of how much you have to manipulate the dict so feel free to add a better answer. The core aspect of this is the use of [tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.loop) to make a counter.

There isn't a way to disable a specific option either. Your best bet would probably be making the options a separate mutable list and removing accordingly.